# OpenSSL inconsistency in C++ and PHP

Tags: php, c++, openssl

I'm trying to write a piece of code for encrypting/decrypting data (e.g. passwords) which will be stored in DB. The goal is that data can be used in C++, PHP and Java. The problem is I’m not getting same encrypted data in C++ and PHP (I’m not dealing with Java jet).
C++ code:

```
void CSSLtestDlg::TryIt()
{
    CString msg, tmp;

    /* A 256 bit key */
    unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *)"01234567890123456789012345678901";
    /* A 128 bit IV */
    unsigned char *iv = (unsigned char *)"01234567890123456";
    /* Message to be encrypted */
    unsigned char *plaintext = (unsigned char *)"Some_plain_text";

    msg = "Original text is: Some_plain_text";

    /* Buffer for ciphertext. Ensure the buffer is long enough for the
    * ciphertext which may be longer than the plaintext, dependant on the
    * algorithm and mode
    */
    unsigned char ciphertext[128];

    /* Buffer for the decrypted text */
    unsigned char decryptedtext[128];

    int decryptedtext_len, ciphertext_len;
    /* Initialise the library */
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    OPENSSL_config(NULL);

    /* Encrypt the plaintext */
    ciphertext_len = encryptIt (plaintext, strlen ((char *)plaintext), 
        key, iv, ciphertext);

    ciphertext[ciphertext_len] = '\0';

    tmp.Format("\nEncrypted text (in HEX) is: %s", StrToHex(ciphertext));
    msg += tmp;

    /* Decrypt the ciphertext */
    decryptedtext_len = decryptIt(ciphertext, ciphertext_len, 
        key, iv, decryptedtext);

    /* Add a NULL terminator. We are expecting printable text */
    decryptedtext[decryptedtext_len] = '\0';

    tmp.Format("\nDecrypted text is: %s", decryptedtext);
    msg += tmp;

    AfxMessageBox(msg);

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_cleanup();
    ERR_free_strings();
}

int CSSLtestDlg::encryptIt(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, 
 unsigned char *key,  unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *ciphertext)
{
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

  int len;

  int ciphertext_len;

  /* Create and initialise the context */
  if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();

  /* Initialise the encryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
   * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
   * In this example we are using 256 bit AES (i.e. a 256 bit key). The
   * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
   * is 128 bits */
  if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
    handleErrors();

  /* Provide the message to be encrypted, and obtain the encrypted output.
   * EVP_EncryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
   */
  if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
    handleErrors();
  ciphertext_len = len;

  /* Finalise the encryption. Further ciphertext bytes may be written at
   * this stage.
   */
  if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len)) handleErrors();
  ciphertext_len += len;

  /* Clean up */
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

  return ciphertext_len;
}

int CSSLtestDlg::decryptIt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, 
unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *plaintext)
{
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

  int len;

  int plaintext_len;

  /* Create and initialise the context */
  if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();

  /* Initialise the decryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
   * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
   * In this example we are using 256 bit AES (i.e. a 256 bit key). The
   * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
   * is 128 bits */
  if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
    handleErrors();

  /* Provide the message to be decrypted, and obtain the plaintext output.
   * EVP_DecryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
   */
  if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
    handleErrors();
  plaintext_len = len;

  /* Finalise the decryption. Further plaintext bytes may be written at
   * this stage.
   */
  if(1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len)) handleErrors();
  plaintext_len += len;

  /* Clean up */
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

  return plaintext_len;
}
```

Result:

```
Original text is: Some_plain_text
Encrypted text (in HEX) is: 39D35A2E6EF8F8E36F3BC1FD8B6B32
Decrypted text is: Some_plain_text
```

PHP code:

```
$key = "01234567890123456789012345678901";
$iv = "01234567890123456";
$msg = "Some_plain_text";

if(function_exists('openssl_encrypt'))
{
    echo("Original text is:" . $msg . "<br>");
    $encrypted_msg = openssl_encrypt($msg, "aes-256-cbc", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    if ($encrypted_msg == FALSE)
        $log->logDebug("openssl_encrypt error!");
    else
    {
        echo("Encrypted text (in HEX) is:" . strToHex($encrypted_msg) . "<br>");
        $decrypted_msg = openssl_decrypt($encrypted_msg, "aes-256-cbc", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA , $iv);
        echo("Decrypted text is:" . $decrypted_msg . "<br>");
    }
}
else echo("openssl_encrypt doesn't exists!<br>");

function strToHex($string)
{
    $hex = '';
    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++)
    {
        $ord = ord($string[$i]);
        $hexCode = dechex($ord);
        $hex .= substr('0'.$hexCode, -2);
    }
    return strToUpper($hex);
}
```

Result:

```
Original text is:Some_plain_text
Encrypted text (in HEX) is:39D35A2E6EF8F8E36F3BC1FD8B06B302
Decrypted text is:Some_plain_text
```

So I’m getting 39D35A2E6EF8F8E36F3BC1FD8B6**B32** (C++) opposite to 39D35A2E6EF8F8E36F3BC1FD8B06**B302** (PHP). In the end a HEX data is going to be stored in DB and retrieved later on. Thanks in advance for all the help and sorry for my bad language.

Comment: Please show `StrToHex`. It sounds like you are using a format string of ***`"%X"`***, and not ***`"%02X"`***.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was in C++ code in  StrToHex() function (which I forget to post in original question) so here it is:

```
CString StrToHex(unsigned char* str)
{       
    CString tmp;
    CString csHexString;    
    int nCount = strlen((char *)str);            
    for( int nIdx =0; nIdx < nCount; nIdx++ )      
    {          
        int n = str[nIdx];
        //tmp.Format( _T("%X"), n ); --> this is wrong
        tmp.Format( _T("%02X"), n ); // --> this is OK
        csHexString += tmp;      
    }   
    return csHexString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also another extra 0 in the second output (B6/B06).  Those are probably the only low bytes in the output, and you have different format settings.

If you show your C++ StrToHex it's probably a simple format string fix, like %x to %0x.

Comment: Yes @Joey you are right, I've seen it the moment I posted my questions and I've posted corrected StrToHex() function